# Fitting a mesh to a density function

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-probability, euclidean-lattices

Suppose I have a probability density function defined on a region in the plane (in my case, the pdf is of the form $f(x) = \alpha\|x\|^{-\beta}$, and the region is the unit disk).  For large $N$, is it possible to place $N$ points $X_1,\dots,X_N$ in the region so that the points $X_i$ are distributed according to $f(x)$, and also form a mesh of (approximately) equilateral triangles?  This is clearly trivial when $f(x)$ is uniform (just put the $X_i$ in a uniform triangular lattice).

For the non-uniform case, obviously some triangles will be larger than others, but I want each individual triangle to be approximately equilateral (e.g. maximum side length and minimum side length are within 1% of each other, etc.). One possibility for the non-uniform case would be to sample $N$ points independently at random from $f(x)$ and then take their Delaunay triangulation, but I don't think there is a guarantee that the triangles will be roughly equilateral (i.e. some will be long and skinny) as $N$ becomes large.

The picture below is along these lines, if you ignore the big ugly hole in the center; each triangle is roughly equilateral, but points are not uniformly distributed.

[image] [<sup>(source: Wayback Machine)</sup>](https://web.archive.org/web/20140915220830im_/http://menet.umn.edu/~jgc/triangular-lattice.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one possible interpretation of your question.

> Assume a probability density function $f$ is given.
>   Is there a sequence of triangulations $T_n$ with $\varepsilon_n$-equilateral triangles such that counting probability measure on nodes converges to $f$ and $\varepsilon_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

(Say a triangle is $\varepsilon_n$-equilateral if the ratio of maximum side length and minimum side length is $\le 1+\varepsilon$.)

I am almost sure that the answer is "YES" if and only if $f$ is conformal factor of a flat metric;
i.e., if and only if $f=e^{2{\cdot}\phi}$ and $\Delta \phi\equiv 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Anton -- I hadn't made the connection to conformal maps, but that's clearly the right way to think about things. I gather that, in my particular case with $f(x) = \alpha\|x\|^{-\beta}$ on the unit disk, the answer is therefore no?

Comment: @John: Sorry my last comment was not correct, so I delete it.
My answer is OK in the case if $f$ has no zeros and the domain is simply connected.
In particular $f=\alpha{\cdot}|x|^{-\beta}$ is OK once the domain
is simply connected.
$$ $$
If the domain is not simply connected then in addition the holonomy group should be $\mathbb{Z}_6$ in $\mathbb S^1$.
For example $f=|x|^{-2/7}$ should be OK for the annulus (I might make a mistake).
(Constructing a triangulation near zero of $f$ seems to be impossible, so you need to cut it from your domain.)

Comment: Ah, interesting; many thanks for the follow-up.  When you say "$f=\alpha{\cdot}|x|^{-\beta}$ is OK once the domain is simply connected", do you mean that such a triangulation DOES NOT exist for this case (I inferred this from your next example with $|x|^{-2/7}$ on an annulus)?  Also, did the $-2/7$ come from anywhere in particular, or would, say, $-2/3$ work as well?  (I will admit that I do not know what a holonomy group is, and clearly have quite a bit of reading to do)

Comment: Take a cone $C_n$ with angle $n{\cdot}\tfrac\pi3$.
(We need angle proportional to $\tfrac\pi3$ so $C_n$ admits a triangulation in equilateral triangles)
The map $C_n\to \mathbb C$, defined as $z\mapsto z^{6/n}$ is conformal.
The conformal factor is proportional to $(|z|^{6/n-1})^2$. 
So any $\beta= 2-12/n$ will do.
(Sorry if I made a mistake in calculations.)

Answer (score 3):

There is an analogy in mechanics that might help: think of the nodes of the mesh as being connected by springs, which have tension proportional to something meaningful, e.g. the integral of $f(x)$ along the segment $[X_i,X_j]$. Then, if you let it stabilize, you will get a mesh with nodes distributed roughly according to $f$; if you pre-process $f$ to make is smooth enough so that it does not change much on every initial triangle, you should end up with roughly equilateral triangles, too.