# Is there a 3d equivalent of this picture?

Tags: soft-question, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, euclidean-lattices

This question arises apropos of an earlier question I asked that was (***VERY!!!***) helpfully answered by Anton Petrunin:

[Fitting a mesh to a density function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85624/fitting-a-mesh-to-a-density-function)

The picture below is the image of a regular equilateral triangular lattice in the complex plane under the map $z \mapsto z^2$:

[image]

(for whatever reason, I seem to be missing a few links in the picture above, but I hope this is sufficient).  This picture has two nice visual properties, namely that the points are distributed in a "regular" or "predictable" way, and that the density of points becomes more concentrated as we move towards the origin.  My question is, are there configurations of points in 3 dimensions that also have these two visual properties?  Owing to Liouville's theorem, I realize that I won't be nearly as fortunate in constructing a nice and easy conformal mapping, so I'm just looking for any possible way to place points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ where I could get some kind of behavior similar to that pictured above.  The best I can think of would be some sort of concentric geodesic buckyball-type structures, or possibly the cartesian image of a regular lattice in spherical coordinates, but I'm wondering if there's anything that's more interesting.

I should also mention that I don't necessary need the configuration to be "completely regular". That is, I'm happy to tolerate occasional points that are inconsistent with the rest of the configuration; there should just be some kind of visual consistency that one would readily observe by inspection.

Comment: 1. It should be pointed out that the density does not increase indefinitely inside the "black spot" but there is some minimum distance (if the points were really generated as indicated in the text)

2. Would you tolerate, for example (in the planar example) occasional vertices with 5 or 7 incident triangles, or should it be "completely regular"?

Comment: Günter:  Thanks for the comments!  As for 1., yes, indeed it is true that the density pictured does have a finite limit since this was generated from a finite hexagonal mesh.  As for 2., yes, I am certainly happy to tolerate occasional irregular vertices, I'm just trying to get away from a configuration that's completely random.  Will update the question accordingly.

Comment: If you are happy with infinite density, you can use a conformal transformation in 3D - just take a regular lattice and replace all distances to the origin by their inverses.

Comment: Carl, good call!  This never would have occurred to me but suits my purposes quite well.

Comment: Doesn't this conformal transform, while indeed giving infinite density close in, give zero density outside a certain circle?

Comment: @Aaron Yes, as Adam pointed out in his answer.  A more general, and hence nonconformal, solution would be to take a lattice and apply a more arbitrary function to the radial distances.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The restriction to conformal maps is a natural one, as it means that there is no affine distortion in the neighbourhood of a point. Specifically, the Voronoi cells of the points will not be oblated or prolated, which is not the case for non-conformal maps. Once we insist on that restriction, Liouville's theorem insists that the only possibilities are Möbius transformations (compositions of Euclidean transformations and geometric inversions).

It seems like a good idea to invert a lattice, and the dense face-centred cubic lattice is more aesthetically pleasing than the ordinary cubic lattice. Geometric inversion of the face-centred cubic lattice ($A_3 \cong D_3$ in *Sphere Packings, Lattices and Groups*) yields an arrangement of points, all of which are contained within the unit ball, and the density diverges to infinity as you approach the origin. Specifically, we take the set of points:

$$\{ \dfrac{(x,y,z)}{x^2+y^2+z^2} : x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}, \enspace x+y+z \equiv 1 \mod 2\}$$

Here's a three-dimensional rotating view of the configuration, where I've made the points semitransparent:

[image: A portion of the geometric inversion of the face-centred cubic lattice]

Is this what you're looking for? Unlike your two-dimensional configuration, this is bounded and infinitely dense in any open ball containing the origin.

Answer (score 4):

[image: triangles and parabolas]

**As we can see in the picture, here are the rules.**

1. The pattern has the symmetries of a triangle. I made with blue three rays starting at the origin, and making equal angles.
2. For each blue ray, there is an array of parabolas which are symmetric with respect to that ray.
3. The parabolas symmetric with respect to the same line are distributed so that the distance between the apexes of two consecutive parabolas is larger, when the distance to the center is larger. This follows from the complex map used.
4. Also, the parabolas are larger as the distance to the center increases.
5. The dots are at the intersections between pairs of parabolas.

[image: intersections of parabolas]

**Now, that we know the rules, it is pretty straightforward to generalize to $\mathbb R^3$.**

1. Take a regular tetrahedron, with the center in the origin.
2. Draw four blue rays, starting from origin, and going through the four vertices of the tetrahedron.
3. Build sequences of paraboloids which have as revolution axes the blue rays.
4. Make sure the paraboloids are at the same distances, and have the same ratios, as in the planar case.
5. Draw the dots at the intersections made by triples of paraboloids.

Comment: Can we see the result?

Comment: Unlike in the planar case, the triple intersections of paraboloids will typically not be 4-tuple intersections. Call the 4 types of paraboloids A, B, C, and D. Then it's probably good to divide 3-space into 4 regions. In the first region, only look at intersections of paraboloids from the A,B,C families. In the 2nd region, only look at intersections of paraboloids from the A,B,D families. etc.

Comment: @Jérémy Blanc: I didn't draw the result. I just gave instructions how to be done. We can visualize.

Comment: @André Henriques: I am aware, that's why I said "the intersections made by triples of paraboloids". There are two options here. One is, as you mention, divide the space into 4 regions, and in each region, keep only the intersections of a triple. The other is, just keep them all.

Comment: @ Cristi Stoica. I just wanted to say that, since the 2d picture was nice, would be good to see the 3d picture.

Comment: @Jérémy Blanc. I know, I would like to see it too, so if anyone finds time to do this, I hope will share it with us. If anyone would be interested in doing this, I would suggest that the paraboloids are not displayed, because otherwise we would not be able to see the forest. Just display the dots, and maybe the parabolas which are the intersections of pairs of paraboloids. And also use four colors for the dots, corresponding to the ways to choose three paraboloids out of four. If at some point I will decide to invest time in making this, I will ping you.

Comment: @Cristi: The reason I suggested dividing space into regions and doing what I described above, is that otherwise you have the possibility of having four intersections that live very very close to each other (corresponding to a triple intersection that very narrowly missed being a quadruple intersection).

Comment: @Jérémy Blanc: Yes, it may be so. I proposed the appropriate generalization of the 2d pattern, but if somebody will implement it, may want to modify it, depending on the purpose. I preferred to not speculate what the purpose may be, and what may go wrong with respect to that purpose. If too close four-points will be formed, depending on purpose, one may prefer to keep the pattern, or one may do what you mention. Another solution will be to replace the cvadruplets with their mass center. It is also possible that, at the boundary between two regions like you proposed, this problem will remain.

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers, as this would be a really interesting point set to look at.

Comment: @John Gunnar Carlsson: Thanks, but there's no need for you to accept my answer. The solution you picked is easier to implement, and probably is suited to your actual needs. You asked what the 3d equivalent of your 2d picture is. Finding the correct 3d equivalent and having some fun in the process was enough for me.